# Deuteronomy 1:7 Resume your journey and go to ... the Judean foothills?

Tags: deuteronomy

Christian Standard Bible, Deuteronomy 1:7

> Resume your journey and go to the hill country of the Amorites and their neighbors in the Arabah, the hill country, the **Judean** foothills, the Negev and the sea coast—to the land of the Canaanites and to Lebanon as far as the great river, the Euphrates River.

How does Christian Standard Bible justify the translation of "the Judean foothills"?

Answer (score 3):

When reading this text in the original Hebrew, one of the first things to be noticed is that the verse starts with imperative verbs, i.e. commands.  One of the next things to notice is that those commands say to travel (KJV: take your journey) to a variety of places, both foreign and potentially domestic (slightly ambiguous, but the reference to "mountains" does not specify a foreign location, implying these are local/domestic mountains).

The word "Judean" would have been added by the translators simply to disambiguate the verse, making it clear that these mountains referenced were local, not those of a neighboring country.

Look at the verse in the KJV:

> Turn you, and take your journey, and go to the mount of the Amorites,
> and unto all the places nigh thereunto, in the plain, in the hills,
> and in the vale, and in the south, and by the sea side, to the land of
> the Canaanites, and unto Lebanon, unto the great river, the river
> Euphrates. (Deuteronomy 1:7, KJV)

According to this verse, the people are commanded to journey to a list of places.

- the mount of the Amorites
- all the places nigh thereunto (nearby that mountain)
- in the plain
- in the hills
- in the vale
- in the south
- by the sea side
- to the land of the Canaanites
- unto Lebanon
- unto the great river (Euphrates)

With the first item being an international destination, and the second as well, the next several might appear to be still related to that foreign location.  It seems that the translators, by adding "Judean," wished to avoid that link and lead people to understand that the next places in the list were local references, as opposed to still addressing Amorite territory.

Of course, they have added to the original in doing so, as the word "Judean" is not in the Hebrew.  It is sometimes necessary, when translating, to add words that are not there simply to achieve the same significance or meaning.  I have no desire to defend the translators, only to explain why they may have felt it necessary here.

One of my favorite examples of adding/changing words in translation comes from Genesis 2:17 where God tells Adam and Eve that if they eat the fruit, they will "die die" (Hebrew: muwth muwth).  This is a Hebrew expression--doubling a word for emphasis.  Because English does not see this as grammatically correct, the KJV translators changed the first "die" to "surely," as in "surely die."  But what else could they have done?  Had they said, as in Hebrew, "you will die die," I suppose it would have changed the English grammatical landscape forever.  Maybe they should have.  In any case, they wanted to preserve the Hebrew emphasis while still using correct English grammar.

In this case with Deuteronomy 1:7, the addition of "Judean" serves to clarify which location is referenced.  My main concern would be that, based on my limited understanding of Hebrew, it isn't certain that only local mountains were intended by the expression.  When in doubt, one should err on the side of caution--in this case, not adding anything that might limit the interpretation such that it could no longer mean what may have been intended.

Answer (score 2):

Using "Judean" as carefully described by Polyhat above is a serious mistake. It allows a novice to imagine that Moses quotes God in what is only portrayed as an historical event: Moses speaking to the Israelites in a particular place at a particular time before they  moved into Canaan, and calling the foothills there by a name they would only have in the future, a name not given them yet. I've looked at 6 other translations and none of them used the adjective "Judean".
One used "Shephelah" which we understand to mean those same Judean foothills. That better fits Polyhat's description, and would probably be acceptable as it does not place such an obvious historical gaffe in the mouth of God as quoted by Moses.

Comment: Good point. Stick around. There is no forum like this one :)

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).